# Regex to match if a following named group matches

Tags: regex

`^(?<foo>[a-z]+)?(?<bar>[1-9]+)?$`

I need to match a whitespace if `bar`, which is optional, is present/match. If `bar` is not a match, no whitespace is needed.

`abc 100` is a match

`abc` is a match

`abc_` is not a match (underscore = whitespace)

`abc100` is not a match

EDIT: Sorry, I totally missed an additional requirement.

`100` is also a match. `foo` is optional, so if `foo` is not present, but `bar` is, then there should be no leading whitespace.

Can you advise what I need to do?

Comment: So... match either A or B, or both separated by a space?

Comment: Could be as simple as [`^([a-z]+)?(?:\b ?(\d+))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/Fo4jrM/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PCRE2 compatible regex, you could use this regex:

```
^(?<foo>[a-z]+)?(?(foo)(?(?=\s*(?&bar))\s|)|)(?<bar>\d+)?$
```

It matches:

- `^` : beginning of string
- `(?<foo>[a-z]+)?` : an optional capture group (`foo`), which matches one or more letters
- `(?(foo)(?(?=\s*(?&bar))\s|)|)` : a conditional on capture group `foo`; if `foo` is matched, then the lookahead conditional `\s*(?&bar)` (some number of spaces followed by what is captured in the `bar` group) is tested. If that matches, the next character must be whitespace. If neither condition is matched, this will match an empty string. This enforces that if *both* `foo` and `bar` are captured, there must be a space between them
- `(?<bar>\d+)?` : an optional capture group (`bar`), which matches one or more digits
- `$` : end of string

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Wk6ycW/1)

Comment: Thank you, this solved the question and pointed me in the right direction. I will be asking another question with a better example as to the intent. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested groups:

```
^(?<foo>[a-z]+)(?:\s(?<bar>[0-9]+))?$
```

See [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/mztkR6/3) for a detailed break-down.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I missed a requirement. I added it as an EDIT to the original post.

Comment: @NWoodsman You can make this work too with some adjustments ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qgkzww/1)). To me is unclear yet if you want to match empy strings as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to match either A or B, or both separated by a space. Here's a simple way to make the space only appear at where it is supposed to be:

```
^(?<foo>[a-z]+)?
(?:^|$|(?<!^) (?!$))
(?<bar>[0-9]+)?$
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/p7muJq/1).

The `^` branch cannot match if `(?<foo>)` matched; likewise, `(?<bar>)` cannot match if the `$` branch matched. A more clever (or stupid) way to put it is [`(?>^|$| (?!$))`](https://regex101.com/r/p7muJq/2), which takes advantage of the fact that atomic groups prevent backtracking.

This regex works fine with any engine that supports lookarounds, including PCRE and .NET. It is also independent of `(?<foo>)` and `(?<bar>)`'s content.