# Regex series of optional matches with separator depending on state

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to accept user input in a series of patterns of major increments to minor increments of fluids.

`1gal-1qt-2pt-2cup-5oz`

I need to enforce the order of unit suffix (gal->qt->pt->cup->oz), however any particular increment is optional to allow the user the most expressiveness, for example

- `1gal-6oz` is valid input
- `1gal` is valid
- `6oz` is valid

I intended to extract the numerical value as a capture group.

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77208836/regex-to-match-if-a-following-named-group-matches) which was helpful but ultimately I struggled to apply that question to this question.

The challenges I'm facing are:

1. The visibility of the separator which needs to appear or disappear depending on the presence of a preceding element.
2. The 'optionality' when large parts of the pattern aren't necessary for a valid match, other than there must be at least one `numeral+suffix` match.

Maybe regex is not the best way to represent this and I should be looking at parsing tries, or similar.

How can I accomplish this?

EDIT:

I ran some C# benchmarks with The Fourth Bird's reply and LogiKals reply. First I ran the benchmark to test 6 patterns, memory overhead was the same 31kb. Logikal came in at .5ns whereas T4B came in at .66ns.

Then i upped the test to 1000 iterations and T4B pulled ahead in speed, but not by much. Memory overhead was up in the mb range for 1000 runs.

I don't have the skill with regex to select either as the "best answer" so if someone can advise I would appreciate it. They both were very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I think parsing is a better idea. What programming language are you using? Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Instead of using a regex for this, use `String.Split()` to split the string on `-` delimiters into an array.

Comment: In case of GUI: have separate input components per increment. In case of CLI: why ask for _one_ string? Query user to enter each increment separately. => no parsing (outside of string to number), no regex required. Give the user as few possibility to mess up input as you possibly can.

Comment: Another alternative could be to force an input string like `"gal":1,"qt":1,...`, enclose it in {} and deserialize from json?

Comment: @Fildor That's even more user-unfriendly...

Comment: @InSync it is what it is. Both are forcing a specific input format. Both are kind of inconvenient. But it's magnitudes better in maintainability. Also, OP still did not disclose where he gets the input from. As is, this looks like x-y problem to me.

Comment: Isn't this just a series of optional parts?

Comment: @NWoodsman Just interested why you ignore the other answers in your latest edit. Is there something wrong with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77210254/5527985)? It should perform well and is simple to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution based on regular expressions.

My regex would be something like this:

```
(?=^\d+[a-z]+(?:-\d+[a-z]+)*$)(?:(?<gal>\d+)gal(?=-|$))?-?(?:(?<qt>\d+)qt(?=-|$))?-?(?:(?<pt>\d+)pt(?=-|$))?-?(?:(?<cup>\d+)cup(?=-|$))?-?(?:(?<oz>\d+)oz)?$
```

Writing it in multiple lines for improving readability:

```
(?=^\d+[a-z]+(?:-\d+[a-z]+)*$)
(?:(?<gal>\d+)gal(?=-|$))?-?
(?:(?<qt>\d+)qt(?=-|$))?-?
(?:(?<pt>\d+)pt(?=-|$))?-?
(?:(?<cup>\d+)cup(?=-|$))?-?
(?:(?<oz>\d+)oz)?$
```

The regex is built upon the following patterns:

- Positive lookahead: `(?=^\d+[a-z]+(?:-\d+[a-z]+)*$)`
- Base match: `(?:(?<gal>\d+)gal(?=-|$))?-?`

The first one ensures that a general pattern is respected.

The second one matches a single value, with a [named capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Named_capturing_group) for the number. It ensures that the pattern ends with a hyphen or the end of the string, and it allows to insert an optional hyphen at the end.

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/97Cz1z/1) for a demo.

If you wish, you can replace `(?=-|$)` with the word boundary (`\b`).

With .NET expressions, named groups are called [named matched subexpressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named-matched-subexpressions).

Comment: When your regex solution looks like this, it's time to strongly consider an alternate solution.

Comment: This looks like an interesting solution but I'll have to examine it more closely tomorrow as it is very late in this part of the planet. Mr. Sandman is beckoning. 
@Ouroborus, much of what I have learned about regular expressions comes from studying ones that are so complex that would not likely be used in practice. Please keep that in mind when judging the merits of this one.

Comment: @logi-kal please don't remove it, your answer is likely going to be the accepted solution. I'm experimenting with the other answers now but your readability and the use of both minimal non-capturing groups and clearly named capturing groups makes your answer better than others.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that for any given string:

- "gal" must precede "qt";
- "qt"  must precede "pt";
- "pt"  must precede "cup";
- "cup" must precede "oz";
- each of those five strings appears at most once in the string; and
- at least one of "gal", "qt", "pt", "cup" and "oz" must appear in the string.

The examples given in the question suggest more restrictive requirements, but I have chosen to address the more general and literal interpretation of the question. For example, the following string satisfies the above requirements.

```
"Yes, 1qt is equal to 2 pt or 4 cup"
```

The string will satisfy these requirements if and only if it is matched by the following regular expression:

```
^(?=.*(?:\d|\b)(?:gal|qt|pt|cup|oz)\b)(?:(?!(?:\d|\b)(?:qt|pt|cup|oz)\b).)*(?:(?:\d|\b)gal\b)?(?:(?!(?:\d|\b)(?:gal|pt|cup|oz)\b).)*(?:(?:\d|\b)qt\b)?(?:(?!(?:\d|\b)(?:gal|qt|cup|oz)\b).)*(?:(?:\d|\b)pt\b)?(?:(?!(?:\d|\b)(?:gal|qt|pt|oz)\b).)*(?:(?:\d|\b)cup\b)?(?:(?!(?:\d|\b)(?:gal|qt|pt|cup)\b).)*(?:(?:\d|\b)oz\b)?(?!.*(?:\d|\b)(?:gal|qt|pt|cup|oz)\b)
```

---

I have used the [tempered greedy token technique](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) in the regex. To see how this works consider the regex

```
^(?:(?!(?:\d|\b)(?:gal|qt|pt|cup|oz)\b).)*$
```

It matches one character at a time in such a way that it will match the string only if it does not contain any of the strings `"gal"`, `"qt"`, `"pt"`, `"cup"` or `"oz"`, preceded by a digit or a word boundary  (`\b`) and followed by a word boundary. Because of the word boundary it will match the string (for example) "3 cupcakes".

---

The regular expression has the following elements.

```
^                       # match beginning of string
(?=                     # begin a positive lookahead
  .*                    # match zero or more characters other than line
                        # terminators, as many as possible
  (?:                   # begin a non-capture group
    \d                  # match a digit
    |                   # or
    \b                  # match a word boundary
  )                     # end non-capture group
  (?:gal|qt|pt|cup|oz)  # match one of the 5 2-3 character strings
  \b                    # followed by a word boundary
)                       # end positive lookahead
```

```
(?:                     # begin a non-capture group
  (?!                   # begin negative lookahead
    (?:\d|\b)           # match a digit or word boundary         
    (?:qt|pt|cup|oz)    # match one of the 2-3 char strings
    \b                  # match a word boundary
  )                     # end negative lookahead
  .                     # match any char except a line terminator
)                       # end non-capture group
*                       # execute non-capture group zero or more times
(?:                     # begin a non-capture group
  (?:\d|\b)             # match a digit or word boundary
  gal                   # match a literal
  \b                    # match a word boundary
)                       # end the non-capture group
?                       # optionally match the above capture group
```

```
(?:                     # similar to above
  (?!
    (?:\d|\b)
    (?:gal|pt|cup|oz)
    \b
  )
  .
)*
(?:
  (?:\d|\b)
  qt
  \b
)?
```

```
(?:                     # similar to above
  (?!
    (?:\d|\b)
    (?:gal|qt|cup|oz)
    \b
  )
  .
)*
(?:
  (?:\d|\b)
  pt
  \b
)?
```

```
(?:                     # similar to above
  (?!
    (?:\d|\b)
    (?:gal|qt|pt|oz)
    \b
  )
  .
)*
(?:
  (?:\d|\b)
  cup\b
```

```
(?:                     # similar to above
  (?!
    (?:\d|\b)
    (?:gal|qt|pt|cup)
    \b
  )
  .
)*
(?:
  (?:\d|\b)
  oz
  \b
)?
```

```
(?!                     # begin a negative lookahead
  .*                    # match zero or more chars other than line
                        # terminators, as many as possible
  (?:\d|\b)             # match a digit or word boundary
  (?:gal|qt|pt|cup|oz)  # match one of the 5 2-3 character strings
  \b                    # match a word boundary
)                       # end negative lookahead
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea could be to use [word-boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) [groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) / hyphens:

```
^\b(?:-?(\d+)gal)?(?:-?\b(\d+)qt)?(?:-?\b(\d+)pt)?(?:-?\b(\d+)cup)?(?:-?\b(\d+)oz)?$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/07mApk/1)

The *word boundaries* are meant to validate the placement of `-` or starting/ending with a word character. Also to require at least one item (disallow empty strings).

Comment: I haven't marked answer yet. If you look at "Match 4" in your demo, Group 1 = 1, Group 2 = 1, Group 3 = 2. There would need to be named groups to understand which unit measure each digit represents. If you have time to implement that please do, else I will this weekend and benchmark all.

Comment: @NWoodsman The units can be identified by knowing the group# and using e.g. `string[] units = {"gal", "qt", "pt", "cup", "oz"};` see [this demo at ideone.com](https://ideone.com/fork/yNmr5V). If you don't want to do it this way, just name the groups. Assumed you already know how to process named capturing groups [from your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77208836) (and [@logi-kal's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77209473/5527985)).

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be first asserting the format of the whole string, and then make all the parts optional.

In C# you can use [atomic groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `(?>` to prevent some unnecessary backtracking.

```
^(?=\d+[a-z]+(?:-\d+[a-z]+)*$)(?>(?<gal>\d+)gal-?)?(?>(?<qt>\d)+qt-?)?(?>(?<pt>\d+)pt-?)?(?>(?<cup>\d+)cup-?)?(?>(?<oz>\d+)oz-?)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=\d+[a-z]+(?:-\d+[a-z]+)*$)` Positive lookahead, assert the format of the string, and therefore also at least a single occurrence
- `(?>(?<gal>\d+)gal-?)?` Atomic group, optionally matching 1+ digits in group **gal** followed by the text "gal" and optional hyphen
- `(?>(?<qt>\d)+qt-?)?` The group for **qt**
- `(?>(?<pt>\d+)pt-?)?` The group for **pt**
- `(?>(?<cup>\d+)cup-?)?` The group for **cup**
- `(?>(?<oz>\d+)oz-?)?` The group for **oz**
- `$` End of string

See a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J786BZ/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/ROvvws).

Comment: @CarySwoveland My comment was not meant to delete it..Perhaps update it asserting not an empty string :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird I considered your answer, however I think there's a structural limitation, i.e. the use of atomic groups precludes the use of named capturing groups. Since each unit is optional, I have no way of knowing what is what, since indices of group don't map to the unit (which would be the only way I can see to retrieve the value of the group). 

So maybe your answer could be modified to 1. return 5 groups always (even when not matched) or 2. wrap the atomic group in a named capture.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Maybe a typo, `(\d+)gal` seems to be the typical for all units however `(\d)+qt` is different for `qt`

Comment: @NWoodsman Then you can change the capture groups to named capture groups like this: https://regex101.com/r/dqxSdb/1 Note that `(\d)+qt` is different from `(\d+)qt` as the former captures the value of the last iteration.

Comment: I changed my mind, revised and undeleted my answer.

Comment: @bobblebubble I voted for your answer, as the leading word boundary is a smart move when all is optional. I think the voting and closing of questions related to the regex tag had been controversial for years. In my opinion It's a pity for many of us regex fans that valuable information gets lost or is underrated.

Comment: Unless StackOverflow forces my hand, I intend to benchmark and listen to the comments to mark accepted. Having a commenter with a good answer express approval of *another* answer is a strong meta-vote...

Answer (score 1):

If you want "a non-empty string `^(?!$)`, with optional units in order, where unit is a number `%n`, unit name, and minus if it's not in the end `%d`"

```
%0 = ^(?!$)(%ngal%d)?(%nqt%d)?(%npt%d)?(%ncup%d)?(%noz%d)?$
%d = ($|-(?!$))
%n = \d+
```

it'll look like https://regex101.com/r/RfCKYO/1

```
/^(?!$)(\d+gal($|-(?!$)))?(\d+qt($|-(?!$)))?(\d+pt($|-(?!$)))?(\d+cup($|-(?!$)))?(\d+oz($|-(?!$)))?$/gm
```

(i'm using https://tsplay.dev/dimava-regex101-markup-1 js snippet to use this markup on regex101)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following approach:

1. Split the input string on the delimiter `-` (as @Barmar suggests in their comment to the question post)
2. Then, for each part of the split input string:

   1. Use regex to verify that the part starts with an integer
   2. Verify that the part ends with a valid unit (directly following the integer)
   3. Verify that the unit 'size' is smaller than the preceding unit 'size'

To check whether the part ends with a valid unit (step 2.2), you can use regex to remove the initial integer part, and then try to find the unit in a dictionary that only contains your valid units. (I am recommending a dictionary rather than a hash set due to step 2.3.)

To check whether the unit 'size' is smaller than the preceding unit 'size' (step 2.3), the dictionary containing your valid units could have a 'comparison size' as the value for the unit (key). E.g. the larger the physical unit, the larger the 'comparison size' (`"gal": 4`, `"qt": 3`, and so on).

---

An implementation of this approach could be:

```
private const char Delimiter = '-';

private static readonly Regex StartsWithIntegerRegex = new Regex(@"^(\d+)");

private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> ComparisonSizeByUnit = new()
{
    ["oz"] = 0,
    ["cup"] = 1,
    ["pt"] = 2,
    ["qt"] = 3,
    ["gal"] = 4,
};
```

```
private static bool IsValidQuantityInput(string quantityInput)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(quantityInput))
    {
        return false;
    }

    var quantities = quantityInput.Split(Delimiter);
    
    if (!TryParseQuantity(quantities[0], out var previousUnitComparisonSize))
    {
        return false;
    }
    
    for (var i = 1; i < quantities.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!TryParseQuantity(quantities[i], out var unitComparisonSize))
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (unitComparisonSize >= previousUnitComparisonSize)
        {
            return false;
        }
        
        previousUnitComparisonSize = unitComparisonSize;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

```
private static bool TryParseQuantity(string quantity, out int unitComparisonSize)
{
    var quantityStartsWithInteger = StartsWithIntegerRegex.IsMatch(quantity);
    
    if (!quantityStartsWithInteger)
    {
        unitComparisonSize = 0;
        return false;
    }
    
    var unit = StartsWithIntegerRegex.Replace(quantity, string.Empty);
    
    return ComparisonSizeByUnit.TryGetValue(unit, out unitComparisonSize);
}
```